# Qt - Is there a way to get a list of all custom slots and signals in a class

Tags: c++, qt

I would like to get a list of all custom (not inherited from the base class) slots and signals. Is this even possible? Or do I have to manually do that?

In general slots/signals have names (`const *`), which one can actually use to pass as arguments to a function the inside of which can than use those names to establish/remove a given slot-signal connection.

The reason I want to get all that is to automatically generate a bunch of `QGraphicsItem`s that will represent inputs (slots) and outputs (signals) of a `QGraphicsProxyWidget`. These inputs and outputs are meant for connection to other such nodes (proxy widget + inputs + outputs). By doing so adding a new custom node would be much, much easier.

Comment: Get slots of the class and its parent class, and find the difference?

Comment: Or name your special slots in a special way, so you can just check class's slots and pick the ones with matching name?

Comment: How do I get the slots/signals? I mean slots/signals are after all just functions (even though signals don't have an implementation provided by the developer) and classes usually have other functions than the ones that are appointed to be slots/signals.

Comment: QMetaObject is created for all QObject subclasses, and contains all kinds of nifty data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [QMetaObject](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.6/qmetaobject.html) for this. Iterate through the methods using

> ```
> QMetaMethod   method(int index) const
> int   methodCount() const
> ```

and check the `MethodType` of the `QMetaMethod`

> ```
> MethodType QMetaMethod::methodType() const
> ```
>
> Returns the type of this method (signal, slot, or method).

**Edit:**

You may want to use

> ```
> int QMetaObject::methodOffset() const
> ```
>
> Returns the method offset for this class; i.e. the index position of this class's first member function.

to skip over the methods form the base classes.

---

**Example:** (from @rbaleksandar for a complete answer)

For a given class `MyClass` do:

```
MyClass test;

QMetaObject *moTest = test.metaObject();

QList<QString> slotSignatures;
QList<QString> signalSignatures;

// Start from MyClass members
for(int methodIdx = moTest->methodOffset(); methodIdx < moTest->methodCount(); ++methodIdx) {
  QMetaMethod mmTest = moTest->method(methodIdx);
  switch((int)mmTest.methodType()) {
    case QMetaMethod::Signal:
      signalSignatures.append(QString(mmTest.methodSignature())); // Requires Qt 5.0 or newer
      break;
    case QMetaMethod::Slot:
      slotSignatures.append(QString(mmTest.methodSignature())); // Requires Qt 5.0 or newer
      break;
  }
}

// Just to visualize the contents of both lists
cout << "Slots:" << endl;
foreach(QString signature, slotSignatures) cout << "\t" << signature.toStdString() << endl;
cout << "Signals:" << endl;
foreach(QString signature, signalSignatures) cout << "\t" << signature.toStdString() << endl;
```

Comment: Add info about `methodOffset` since you wanted to skip inherited stuff.

Comment: Hope you don't mind that I added some code to your answer. Thanks a lot!  Very helpful information indeed.

Comment: How to distinguish a `private` or `public` slot by this method? @Thomas

Comment: Not sure why you can't google this yourself, but yes, there is [QMetaMethod::access()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetamethod.html#access) whick will return the access as an [enum QMetaMethod::Access](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetamethod.html#Access-enum)

Comment: Is there a safe way to skip only base class signals added by the QObject base?